# (ERROR) Python: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compare two excel files and I am getting the ValueError. Here is a log of the error I get. This should compare two excel files which I have imported into the project. I am using the pandas library and numpy. This worked when I tried comparing a smaller data set but not for a much larger excel file. Any suggestions on what I could try will be helpful. Thank you

```
[~/Desktop/Compare]$ python3 compare.py
compare.py:11: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  comparevalues = dfnew.values == dfold.values
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Desktop/Compare/compare.py", line 15, in <module>
    rows,cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is what I am trying

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

dfnew = pd.read_excel('files/From_NEW.xlsx')

dfold = pd.read_excel('files/From_OLD.xlsx')

#print(dfnew.equals(dfhroi))

comparevalues = dfnew.values == dfold.values

print(comparevalues)

rows,cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    dfnew.iloc[item[0],item[1]] = ' {} --> {} '.format(dfnew.iloc[item[0], item[1]], dfold.iloc[item[0],item[1]])


dfnew.to_excel('files/output.xlsx', index=False,header=True)
```

Comment: try this `rows,*cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not same number of rows / columns in both DataFrames, so warning for compare numpy arrays and error in `numpy.where`.

You can check it:

```
print (len(dfnew))
print (len(dfold))

print (len(dfnew.columns))
print (len(dfold.columns))
```

For same index and columns in both DataFrames use:

```
idx = dfnew.index.intersection(dfold.index)
cols = dfnew.columns.intersection(dfold.columns)

df1 = dfnew.reindex(index=idx, columns=cols)
df2 = dfold.reindex(index=idx, columns=cols)
```

Then use your solution (with `df1, df2`):

```
comparevalues = df1.values == df2.values

rows,cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)
```

Or:

```
dfnew = df1.mask(df1.ne(df2), df1.astype(str) + '-- >' + df2.astype(str))
dfnew.to_excel('files/output.xlsx', index=False,header=True)
```

Comment: Even if the indexing matches, `comparevalues` would be 1d, a boolean series.

Comment: @hpaulj `comparevalues = dfnew.values == dfold.values` ? If compare DataFrames? I think `values` is not column name